# Unique values on multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need to get a list of unique values from few columns. The data looks like this:
[image: screenshot]

I tried using Unique but it only gives me copy of the list. These 4 lists are already unique values found in another sheet. 
If getting unique from 4 columns is impossible, how would I go around combining these 4 columns but instead merging data from a row to 1 cell I'd like to append that one column to have one city per row (so add more rows). 
Another idea I had - pulling data from multiple sheets into 1 row, but as it's an automated report, number of towns in each sheet changes every time, so can't use specific cell locations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+unique

Comment: @TimWilliams 99% of the answers are for unique values in 1 row. I spend a lot of time trying to find something that would work in my case, I couldn't find anything - I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula (entered into cell `F2` and assuming your data is in range `A1:D5`)

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP("zzzzz",INDEX(IF(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,A$2:D$5),0,A$2:D$5),MIN(IF(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,A$2:D$5),"",ROW(A$2:D$5)-ROW(A$2)+1)),0)),"")
```

As it is an array formula it needs to be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down until there are blank cells

Comment: @That works great, thanks Tom! 
Quick question as I don't use Excel too often (and I'm building an automated report in Google Sheets) - If the values in A1:D5 get updated every week, if I drag the function down on few more cells (even when I see they're empty), will the function update when the values change? Or will I have to run the function every week manually?

Comment: @Coolkidscandie If the values change every week they will automatically be replaced with the new values (provided your calculation settings are set to automatic). If new values are added to your data set, as long as you update the formula to include all the cells you can drag it down and apply it to the new values as well

Answer (score 0):

It does not work in my case, in calc (LibreOffice) that i have exactly the same problem. To extract unique values from multiple columns with text, with blank spaces. I have tried a lot of formulas with no success...

What worked for me - I dont know why this worked for me!
A, B, and C contains text from the 2nd row and onwards. Formula is put on D2 cell as Array formula.

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(
INDEX($A$2:$A$20; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($D$1:D1; $A$2:$A$20)+($A$2:$A$20=""); 0)); 
INDEX($B$2:$B$7; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($D$1:D1; $B$2:$B$7)+($B$2:$B$7=""); 0))
); 
INDEX($C$2:$C$12; MATCH(0; COUNTIF($D$1:D1; $C$2:$C$12)+($C$2:$C$12=""); 0))
); 
"")
```

Found [here](https://www.get-digital-help.com/extract-a-unique-distinct-list-from-three-columns-in-excel/)