# Excel Concatenate a string in multiple columns, count and remove the duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

Currently the stock process at my company is very manual and it normally doesn't get carried out due to the process being rather boring. Currently all excel based I am slowly moving over to SQL that will automatically update the information.

We have come up with a naming system/code for each item, this is made up from several fields on the excel document. However there is the same codes in different columns that we wish to remove for when we push into SQL (Basically we just want the 1 line item and a count of how many times it has been used)

It has to be dynamic. (I can add an extra tab to the excel document to do any magic required) and if possible not use any Macros

So the data starts like this:

[image]
#Counts and then the duplicates are removed to produce this list

[image]

I have tried a range of countifs/Vlookups and I can get it roughly working but its not dynamic enough and I end up having multiple rows of 0 Qtys

Hopefully this is enough information

Cheers all

Comment: Can you post the data as text rather than images? Also, can you post what you've tried so far? For example, how are you getting the unique list and what formulas have you tried for the counts?

Comment: Tagged with VBA but you say you don't want to use VBA?

Comment: What version of Excel?  Windows or Mac?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like a very similar question [was answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224294/unique-values-on-multiple-columns)
After plugging in that formula in a different column, you can use the CountIf function in the next column.